# Unwanted callback from `SFSpeechRecognizer` `recognitionTask` at ~30s mark

Tags: macos, sfspeechrecognizer

If I inspected the stamps for callbacks from the `SFSpeechRecognizer` `recognitionTask` callback (on macOS):

```
        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask( with: recognitionRequest )
        { result, error in
            // if more than two seconds elapsed since the last update, we send a notification
            NSLog( "speechRecognizer.recognitionTask callback" )
            :
```

... I observe:

```
:
2019-11-08 14:51:00.35 ... speechRecognizer.recognitionTask callback
2019-11-08 14:51:00.45 ... speechRecognizer.recognitionTask callback

2019-11-08 14:51:32.31 ... speechRecognizer.recognitionTask callback
```

i.e. There is an additional unwanted callback approximately 30 seconds after my last utterance.

`result` is `nil` for this last callback.

The fact that it's close to 30 seconds suggests to me it is representing a max-timeout.

I'm not expecting a time out, because I have manually shutdown my session (at around the 5s mark, by clicking a button):

```
    @objc
    func stopRecording()
    {
        print( "stopRecording()" )

        // Instructs the task to stop accepting new audio (e.g. stop recording) but complete processing on audio already buffered.
        // This has no effect on URL-based recognition requests, which effectively buffer the entire file immediately.
        recognitionTask?.finish()

        // Indicate that the audio source is finished and no more audio will be appended
        recognitionRequest?.endAudio()

        //self.recognitionRequest = nil

        audioEngine.stop()

        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap( onBus: 0 )

        //recognitionTask?.cancel()

        //self.recognitionTask = nil

        self.timer?.invalidate()

        print( "stopRecording() DONE" )
    }
```

There's a lot of commented out code, as it seems to me there is some process I'm failing to shut down, but I can't figure it out.

Complete code is [here](https://gist.github.com/p-i-/0c5dfff537c1ac7c53db9e5688767056).

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: in this solution, there is still one unwanted callback immediately after the destruction sequence is initiated. Hence I'm not going to accept the answer yet. Maybe there exists a more elegant solution to this problem, or someone may shed light on observed phenomena.

The following code does the job:

```
        is_listening = true
        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask( with: recognitionRequest )
        { result, error in
            if !self.is_listening {
                NSLog( "IGNORED: speechRecognizer.recognitionTask callback" )
                return
            }

            // if more than two seconds elapsed since the last update, we send a notification
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            NSLog( "speechRecognizer.recognitionTask callback" )
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { _ in
                if !self.is_listening {
                    print( "IGNORED: Inactivity (timer) Callback" )
                    return
                }
                print( "Inactivity (timer) Callback" )
                self.timer?.invalidate()
                NotificationCenter.default.post( name: Dictation.notification_paused,  object: nil )
                //self.stopRecording()
            }
        :
    }


    @objc
    func stopRecording()
    {
        print( "stopRecording()" )

        is_listening = false

        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        audioEngine.inputNode.reset()

        recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
        recognitionRequest = nil

        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil;

        recognitionTask?.cancel()
        recognitionTask = nil
    }
```

The exact sequence is taken from https://github.com/2bbb/ofxSpeechRecognizer/blob/master/src/ofxSpeechRecognizer.mm -- I'm not sure to what extent it is order sensitive.

For starters, that destruction sequence seems to eliminate the 30s timeout? callback.

However the closures still get hit after `stopListening`.

To deal with this I've created an `is_listening` flag.

I have a hunch Apple should maybe have internalised this logic within the framework, but meh it works, I am a happy bunny.