# How to make SFSpeechRecognizer available on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, sfspeechrecognizer

I am trying to use Apple's Speech framework to do speech recognition on macOS 10.15.1. Before macOS 10.15, speech recognition was only available on iOS, but according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer) and [this talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/256/#), should now be available on macOS as well.

However, all my my attempts to use it have resulted in the `SFSpeechRecognizer`'s `isAvailable` property being set to false. Per that talk and the documentation I've enabled Siri and made sure that my app has the `"Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description"` key set to a string value in Info.plist.

I've also tried enabling code signing (which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783197/bypass-disable-macos-security-measures-for-efficient-development-cycle-of-sfspee) suggests might be necessary), enabling Dictation under Keyboard > Dictation in the System preferences.

Here's some example code, although the specifics probably aren't important; I've tried it using a Storyboard instead of SwiftUI, putting the instantiation of the `SFSpeechRecognizer` inside and outside the `requestAuthorization` callback, leaving the locale unspecified, etc. Nothing seems to have any effect:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Speech

struct ContentView: View {

    func tryAuth() {
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
            switch authStatus {
                case .authorized:
                    print("authorized")
                case .denied:
                    print("denied")
                case .restricted:
                    print("restricted")
                case .notDetermined:
                    print("notDetermined")
                @unknown default:
                    print("unanticipated auth status encountered")
            }
        }
    }

    func speechTest() {
        guard let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US")) else {
            // Not supported for device's locale
            print("couldnt get recognizer")
            return
        }

        if !recognizer.isAvailable {
            print("not available")
            return
        }

        print("Success")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Try auth") {
                self.tryAuth()
            }
            Button("Test") {
                self.speechTest()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's especially odd is that if I run the app and then click the "Try auth" button, the `authStatus` returned from the callback is always `.authorized`. However, I've never been presented with a dialog asking me to authorize the app, and the app doesn't show up in the list of authorized apps under System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Speech Recogniztion.

Nonetheless, clicking the "Test" button afterwards results in printing `not available`.

It seems like there's some hole in my understanding of the macOS privacy/permissions system, but I'm not sure how to debug further. I also think it should be possible to get this working, because I've seen other questions on StackOverflow suggesting that people have done so, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774314/unwanted-callback-from-sfspeechrecognizer-recognitiontask-at-30s-mark), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893935/how-to-select-audio-input-device-mic-in-avaudioengine-on-macos-swift).

EDIT: At the suggestion of a comment, I tried simply ignoring the fact that `isAvailable` is false by replacing my check for it with code to actually try to transcribe a file, e.g.:

```swift
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/james/Downloads/test.wav"))

recognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { (result, error) in
    guard let result = result else {
        print("There was an error transcribing that file")
        print("print \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if result.isFinal {
        print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
    }
}
```

Then it fails, printing: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (kAFAssistantErrorDomain error 1700.)`. So it seems like it really is necessary to check for `isAvailable`, and my question remains: how to get it to be `true`?

Comment: What is the source of audio?

Comment: @ElTomato So far I haven't even gotten as far as providing audio to be transcribed, since it won't work without the `SFSpeechRecognizer`'s `isAvailable` property being `true`. That said, if I ignore that, don't check for availability first, and just provide a file to be transcribed from a URL, it fails with `"The operation couldn’t be completed. (kAFAssistantErrorDomain error 1700.)"`. I've edited the original question to reflect that I've tried this.

Comment: I have the same issue, but in my case `kAFAssistantErrorDomain` error code is 601.

Comment: This now appears to work fine! (on Ventura)

Comment: You must give permissions to access computer microphone. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76836073/4815438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar problems with SFSpeechRecognizer... Perhaps you can set the delegate of `SFSpeechRecognizer` before requesting for authorization, as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/asking_permission_to_use_speech_recognition).

For example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
  var speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
    speechRecognizer.delegate = self
  }

  override func viewWillAppear() {
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
       ...
    }

    if !speechRecognizer.isAvailable {
      print("Not available!")
    }

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)

    // will now ask for authorisation
    speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { (result, error) in
        ...
    }
  }
}

extension ViewController: SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

}
```

Then [the authorisation dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA80x.png) will be properly shown.

In addition, it seems that only when there is a call to `recognitionTask`, that the user will be asked to give permission. Instead, calling `requestAuthorization` alone will not have any effect.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! I probably should have tried setting a delegate, but frustrating that they don't explicitly state in the documentation that it's a requirement.